# Does this sink detach from the bathroom countertop?

Tags: bathroom, sink, countertops

Our countertop is perfectly fine, but we'd like to maybe get new sinks because they are scratched and have aged over the years due to water damage, cleaning products, etc.

Does this sink detach from the countertop or not?

Bonus question: Can anyone figure out what material this countertop is based on the images?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: if you need me to add more images, let me know.

Comment: yes it does detach ... no, you can only guess about the material, if pictures are the only source of information

Comment: Looks like a glue/caulk/sealer is all that is is holding it on.  Remove drain pipe and carefully pry up the sink.  Use cloth or better wood to protect counter top from tools(pry bar/big screwdriver).  Finding a sink that is similar colour/shape might be the difficult job.

Comment: If it was set down with silicone caulk, it might be best to try cutting through it. I’d try a flexible knife that you can press down to lay flat against the counter top.